What anthropology questions should be routed towards History.SE?
Both History.SE and CogSci.SE have anthropology tags. What makes an anthropology question relevant to CogSci.SE vs. History.SE vs. neither?

General Anthopological questions would be off-topic and should be migrated to History.SE, however, if the question is in the realms of Psychological Anthropology then it is on-topic for this site.
Anthropology is

the study of various aspects of humans within past and present societies

Psychological Anthropology

is an interdisciplinary subfield of anthropology that studies the interaction of cultural and mental processes.

Social Anthropology and Cultural Anthropology

study the norms and values of societies

Linguistic Anthropology

studies how language affects social life

and the list can continue.
Whilst Anthropology is on topic if it is Psychological Anthropology I believe the Anthropology tag needs amending to suit - i.e. Psychological-Anthropology
